# Facebook Chat turned off can you people see your activity

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

If facebook chat is turned off, can people see your activity (what you are liking etc) in the right hand side?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Even if your chat is turned off, your activity such as comments,posts, liking etc will appear on the news feed of people present in your friends list.

Answer (score 0):

The option to disable the chat for some or all of your contacts should only affect your status (the "online indicator"/green dot) for them.